# Getting 'Timeout of 2000ms exceeded' error in mocha

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js

So i have this code below. It deletes the db and adds two users for test case.
when i verify it manually in mongo database everything shows correct but in mocha test case I get the timeout error even after defining the done argument and calling it.

Please help me on this.

```js
const users = [{
  _id: new ObjectID(),
  email: 'First'
}, {
  _id: new ObjectID(),
  email: 'Second'
}];

beforeEach((done) => {
  User.remove({}).then(() => {
    return User.insertMany(users);
  }).then(() => done());
 
})
```

Comment: Could be that `return User.insertMany(users);` throws an error. Try adding a `catch` statement to your future and see if it gets invoked.

Comment: By "future" I mean "promise" :)

Comment: no, i tried that but no error is caught.. it has the same error outputted..

Answer (score 0):

In mocha, tests will time out after 2000 ms by default. Even if you were handling the asynchrony 100% correctly (which you are not), if you do an async operation that takes longer than 2 seconds, mocha will assume a failure. This is true even if the async operation is in a `beforeEach` or some other hook.

To change this, you need to invoke the `timeout` method on the test instance, giving it a sufficiently-high value. To access the test instance, you need to define your test functions using the `function` keyword rather than arrow syntax, and it will be available as `this` in your test functions:

```
beforeEach(function(done) {
  this.timeout(6000); // For 6 seconds.
  User.remove({}).then(() => {
    return User.insertMany(users);
  }).then(() => done());
});
```

In what way could you handle the asynchrony here better, though? As Henrik pointed out in comments, you'll never call `done` if either of your database calls fail. To be honest, though, since you're already dealing with promises, you shouldn't even use the `done` callback. Instead, just use Mocha's built-in promise support by returning the chained promise.

```
beforeEach(function() {
  this.timeout(6000); // For 6 seconds.
  return User.remove({})
    .then(() => User.insertMany(users));
});
```

This way, if either of those promises rejects, Mocha will know and will show the rejection instead of just sitting around waiting for your test to time out.

You can even use `async/await` instead if you prefer:

```
beforeEach(async function() {
  this.timeout(6000); // For 6 seconds.
  await User.remove({});
  await User.insertMany(users);
});
```